# Angular-file-upload

Tags: angularjs, fileupload, asp.net-web-api, angularjs-controller

Мне нужно сделать загрузку файлов на сервер. Я использую для этого **angularjs** и **web api** (который обращается к wcf сервису). Я решил использовать этот пример: http://nervgh.github.io/pages/angular-file-upload/examples/simple/. Я получаю название файла и размер, но как получить путь к файлу на локальном компьютере, или массив байтов. Как это работает?

Мой метод в ApiController:

```
[HttpPost]
public AttachmentDto CreateAttachment(JObject json)
{
    using (var _client = new DataServiceClient("epData"))
    {
        if (Properties.Settings.Default.Domain != "")
        {
            _client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName = Properties.Settings.Default.Domain + "\\" + Properties.Settings.Default.Login;
            _client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.Password = Properties.Settings.Default.Password;
        }
        var userId = json["userId"].ToObject<Guid>();
        _client.SetCurrentUser(userId);


        var filePath = json["filePath"].ToObject<string>();

        var originalFilePath = Convert.FromBase64String(filePath);
        var fileName = json["fileName"].ToObject<string>();
        var categoryId = json["categoryId"].ToObject<Guid>();

        var result = _client.CreateAttachment(fileName, categoryId, data);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Главный вопрос в том как мне получить путь к локальному файлу, я не пойму как работает этот пример, он выдает размер файла, его название. Но чтобы загрузить его мне нужен путь файла, или массив байтов. Ни того ни другого там нет, или я не нашел.

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы отправить файлы на сервер надо инициализировать FileUploader,

```
$scope.uploaderImages = new FileUploader({
    url: 'http://newsimageupload/' + newsService.editNews.id,
    removeAfterUpload: true
});
```

А для загрузки вызвать метод:

```
 $scope.uploaderImages.uploadAll();
```

А всю работу с файлами уже решили в библиотеке.

Comment: судя по всему вопрос про сервер, а не клиент

Comment: тут про серверную часть и непонятно чего именно хотел автор